# Maxmind GeoIP2 tutorial (How-to)?

Tags: maxmind, geoip2

I used GeoIp, with pure PHP codes..
but GeoIp2 become namespaced and etc, and at this moment i couldnt find out how to use that.. i have downloaded `GeoLite2-Country.mmdb`, and now how to get the country name for IP, i.e. `123.123.123.123`.

p.s. I dont have GIT/COMPOSER or etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How i did it:   let's say, create a folder named "**My_Folder**" and inside it:

1)  create folder **`GeoIp2`** and put in it content of this "SRC" folder ([download](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php/archive/master.zip)).

2) put **`MaxMind`** folder ([download](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php/archive/master.zip), from "SRC" folder). 

3) place i.e. **`GeoLite2-Country.mmdb`** ([download](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)).

then, in **My_Folder**  create a `example.php` file and put this code:

```
$user_ip='123.123.123.123';

spl_autoload_register('func888'); function func888($class){ include_once(str_replace(array('/','\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, dirname(__file__)."/$class.php")) ;}
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader; 
//you can do it for "city" too.. just everywhere change phrase "country" with "city".
try{
    $reader = new Reader(dirname(__file__)."/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");
    $record = $reader->country($user_ip);
    $reader->close();
    $country_name =  $record->raw['country']['names']['en'];
} catch ( GeoIp2\Exception\AddressNotFoundException $e ){    $country_name = 'not_found';  }

echo $country_name;
// RESULTS -------------- > China
```

p.s. other examples found at:https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php

Comment: MaxMind also distributes a Phar file with that includes the dependencies, which can be loaded more simply without using Composer.

Comment: @oschwald please, if you can, write an answer with examples, many noobs need that.